# Oracle PLSQL - Como obter o menor e maior valor de uma lista de valores em um range?

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

```
CREATE TABLE TABELA_PRAZO
(
    CEP_INICIO NUMBER(8) NOT NULL, 
    CEP_FIM NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,
    PRAZO NUMBER(3) NOT NULL
);

insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (1000000, 1000005, 5);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (510101, 510104, 4);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (510000, 510067, 4);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (510068, 510100, 3);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (1000006, 10000010, 5);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (810000, 810001, 5);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (810002, 810003, 5);
insert into tron2000.TABELA_PRAZO(CEP_INICIO, CEP_FIM, PRAZO) values (810004, 810005, 5);
```

A tabela descreve os prazos que devem ser usados por um sistema de cálculo de frete, dada uma faixa de *CEP* (faixa de CEP é um intervalo entre `CEP_INICIO` e `CEP_FIM`, ambos inclusos no intervalo). Segue um pequeno exemplo da tabela populada:

> ```
> CEP_INICIO   CEP_FIM   PRAZO
> 1000000      1000005   5
> 510101       510104    4
> 510000       510067    4
> 510068       510100    3
> 1000006      10000010  5
> 810000       810001    5
> 810002       810003    5
> 810004       810005    5
> ```

Tendo isto, como vou escrever uma *query* ou *procedure* em Oracle que una os registros cujas faixas de CEP com mesmo prazo são consideradas “vizinhas”?
 Considera-se que duas faixas de CEP são “vizinhas”, quando o `CEP_FIM` da primeira adicionando 1 é igual `CEP_INICIO` da segunda, eambas têm o mesmo prazo?

No caso acima, resultado do processo seria:

> ```
> CEP_INICIO CEP_FIM  PRAZO
> 1000000    10000010 5
> 510101     510104   4
> 510000     510067   4
> 510068     510100   3
> 810000     810005   5
> ```

Quem puder, dá uma força aí galera.

Comment: o que você já tem de código?

Comment: Esta ideia de CEP vizinho "+1" não deve funcionar , creio eu , pois tem intervalos vizinhos maiores que um. Existe a garantia de não haver faixas sobrepostas ? Qual o objetivo disto ? Reduzir a quantidade de registros ? Só exibir numa consulta ?

Comment: Então, os intervalos vizinhos maiores que um são de faixas diferentes, o objeto proposto nessa minha dúvida é obter em uma unica linha o menor e maior numero de CEP de uma faixa que se completa dentro do mesmo prazo, como no exemplo: O cep 810000 vai até 810005 em 3 faixas do mesmo prazo. Tô quebrando a cabeça aqui mas não consigo pensar em uma solução pra fazer isso.

Comment: Mas você "enxugar" a tabela ou só a saída da consulta ? Tentou algo como cep_inicio+1=cep_fim no join ? Sigo sem entender o "problema" pois o objetivo da tabela é calcular o prazo e não creio que o número de linhas interfira muito nisto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui desenvolver uma solução, porém, a nivel operacional, talvez não tenha a performance desejada, mas a baixa escala atende 100%.

```
create or replace procedure insert_compactado is
  cursor c_1 is
    select * from TABELA_PRAZO order by cep_inicio asc;
  r_1        c_1%rowtype;
  cep_min    NUMBER(8);
  cep_max    NUMBER(8);
  cep_inicio NUMBER(8);
  prazo      number(1);
  vcount      number(3);
begin
  cep_min    := null;
  cep_max    := null;
  cep_inicio := null;
  prazo      := null;
  open c_1;
  fetch c_1
    into r_1;
  while c_1%found loop
    cep_min := r_1.cep_inicio;
    cep_max := r_1.cep_fim;
    prazo   := r_1.prazo;
    vcount := null;
    FETCH c_1
      INTO r_1;
      while r_1.cep_inicio = cep_max + 1 and r_1.prazo = prazo loop
        cep_max := r_1.cep_fim;
        FETCH c_1 INTO r_1;
        while cep_inicio = r_1.cep_fim - 1 and r_1.prazo = prazo and cep_max < r_1.cep_fim loop
          cep_inicio := cep_min;
          cep_max := r_1.cep_fim;
        end loop;
      end loop;
    begin
      select nvl(count(1),0)
        into vcount
        from TABELA_PRAZO_COMPACTADO t
       where t.cep_inicio = cep_min
         and t.cep_fim = cep_max
         and t.prazo = prazo;
    end;
    if vcount = 0 then 
      begin
        insert into TABELA_PRAZO_COMPACTADO(cep_inicio,
                                            cep_fim,
                                            prazo)
                                     values(cep_min,
                                            cep_max,
                                            prazo);
      end;           
    end if;
  end loop;
  close c_1;
  commit;
end;
```